# Creating a custom json from existing json

Tags: python, json

I have Json something like below

**Input Json**

```
  "blocks": [
            {
                "key": "",
                "text": "Contents",
                "type": "unstyled",
                "depth": 0,
                "inlineStyleRanges": [
                    {
                        "offset": 0,
                        "length": 8,
                        "style": "BOLD"
                    }
                ],
                "entityRanges": [],
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "key": "",
                "text": "1.\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Completed\n Activities & Accomplishments\u00a0 1",
                "type": "unstyled",
                "depth": 0,
                "inlineStyleRanges": [],
                "entityRanges": [
                    {
                        "offset": 0,
                        "length": 49,
                        "key": 0
                    }
                ],
                "data": {}
            },
            {
                "key": "",
                "text": "2.\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Planned Activities for\n Next Reporting Period\u00a0 3",
                "type": "unstyled",
                "depth": 0,
                "inlineStyleRanges": [],
                "entityRanges": [
                    {
                        "offset": 0,
                        "length": 55,
                        "key": 1
                    }
                ],
                "data": {}
            },
```

I am trying to extract "text" key data and want to convert it into new json in the key value format
I am able to extract text properly now I just wanna know how to separate numeric from letters successfully

```
def jsontojson():
    with open('C:\Extraction\Docs\TMS TO 692M15-22-F-00073 Monthly Status _ Financial Report July 2022.json') as json_file:
        # json1=json_file.read()
        json1=json.load(json_file)

        value=""
        for dict1 in json1["blocks"]:
            # print(dict1)
            
            for key in dict1:
                
                if key=="text":
                    value+=dict1[key]
                    dict2={}
                    d=value.split()
                    print("Value of d",d)
                    if str(d).isdigit():
                        dict2['key1']=d
                    else:
                        dict2['desciption']=d

                    

                    print("Dictionary is",dict2['key'])
```

For the above code it gives me Key error : key1

**Let me know where i am wrong or what I need to do so that i can get the Output**

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
[
      {
        "key": "",
        "text": "Contents"
    },
    {
        "key": "1.",
        "text": "Completed Activities & Accomplishments"
    },
    {
        "key": "2.",
        "text": "Planned Activities for Next Reporting Period"

    },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (`json1` contains the data from your question):

```py
import re

out = []
for d in json1["blocks"]:
    num = re.search(r"^(\d+\.)\s*(.*)", d["text"].replace("\n", ""))

    out.append(
        {
            "key": num.group(1) if num else "",
            "text": (num.group(2) if num else d["text"]).rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0],
        }
    )

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"key": "", "text": "Contents"},
    {"key": "1.", "text": "Completed Activities & Accomplishments"},
    {"key": "2.", "text": "Planned Activities for Next Reporting Period"},
]
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution but I am getting below error 

  File "C:\Extraction\Doc_Extract\functions.py", line 92, in json2json
    "text": (num.group(2) if num else dict1["text"]).rsplit(maxsplit=1)[0],
IndexError: list index out of range

Also the input json file has more contents than what I have shared above, is it something related to that ?

Comment: @amnpawar Yes, it's related with values you have in your Json. I suggest to debug the script and see what values are in the key `"text"` and then adjust the regex/rsplit appropriately.

Comment: Was able to fix the issue using rsplit(' ',maxsplit=1)[0] 
Now I am trying to cover 1.1.2.3 & 4.1.2.5.3 and their similar occurences , I changed the regex to r"^(\d+)|^((\.(\d+))+)*\s*(.*)"  but it started giving me error as 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'. Let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Another and easy way is (if your first list is called "Mylist" :

```
new_list =[]

for dic in Mylist:
    new_list.append({'key':dic['key'],
                     'text':dic['text']})
```

Comment: thank you for your response but actually it won't give the output with extracted key values from the text else it will return keys as empty values along with the text.

{
        "key": "",
        "text": "Contents"
    },
    {
        "key": "",
        "text": "1.\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Completed\n Activities & Accomplishments\u00a0 1"
    },
    {
        "key": "",
        "text": "2.\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Planned Activities for\n Next Reporting Period\u00a0 3"
    },

which isn't expected.